# Where are the private / public key files stored when creating them with cardano-cli?

Tags: cardano-cli

I am using the cardano-cli for creating the signing / verification keys.

```
cardano-cli address key-gen --verification-key-file pay.vkey --signing-key-file pay.key
```

Does anybody know where these files are stored?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are located in the directory where you enter the command.
In the terminal, type in `pwd` and that will show you where your working on your system. Once you run the cardano-cli commands, type in `ls`  to view all folders and files in that directory.